# Drupal 8 YAML Form Module: How do I change the value of a Hidden element?

Tags: yaml, drupal-8

A few days ago I asked a question about [Drupal 8 YAML Form Module: Populate Select Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421252/drupal-8-yaml-form-module-populate-select-element). I found a solution that it works fine for me.

But now I've got a new doubt. I would like to change the value of a Hidden element and depending of this value, to show some elements in the form or not. I'm trying to implement the hook `hook_yamlform_element_info_alter(array &$elements)` and I do `$elements['hidden_element_name']['#value'] = 'New value of the hidden element'` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: [How do I change the value of a Hidden element?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220308/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-a-hidden-element/220404)

Basically, I've implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` and I do:

```
$form['elements']['hidden_element_name']['#value'] = 'New value of the hidden element';
```

I hope it helps someone!